# Rendering VHDL in latex

Tags: listings, packages, code, rendering

I have a VHDL code which I want to insert into my latex document. 
I need a package that takes care of syntax highlighting, indentation etc.
Is there a package which serves this purpose?

Comment: You should post your MWE with `listings`, since it does have support for syntax highlighting for VHDL.

Comment: @rainer you're right! And I realised this long after posting this question. Anyways, I've updated the question. Thanks for bringing this to my notice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [`minted`](https://github.com/gpoore/minted) package includes support for VHDL code. It uses the Python module [Pygments](http://pygments.org) to provide syntax highlighting, and Pygments supports VHDL.<sup>1</sup>

Once it’s installed, you get syntax highlighting, which can be configured in lots of ways (see the package documentation). You'll also need to use the `-shell-escape` flag when you run the file, since LaTeX is calling an external program (Pygments) to do the highlighting.

You can either type (VHDL) code directly into the document, using `\begin{minted}{vhdl} ... \end{minted}` or use `\inputminted{vhdl}{somefile.vhdl}` to include code from an external file:

Here's a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}

This is some VHDL code:

\begin{minted}{vhdl}
process
begin
  CLK <= '1'; wait for 10 NS;
  CLK <= '0'; wait for 10 NS;
end process;
\end{minted}

and here I can drop in an external file:

\inputminted{vhdl}{wikipedia.vhdl}

\end{document}
```

I'd never heard of VHDL before, so the example code is taken from the [Wikipedia page for VHDL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VHDL).

This is what you get with those default settings:

[image]

The documentation (available [on GitHub](https://github.com/gpoore/minted/blob/master/source/minted.pdf)) goes into much more detail about how to customise the syntax highlighting, style, layout and so on.

---

<sup>1</sup> You can check if a language is supported by Pygments by running

```
pygmentize -L lexers
```

at a command line and inspecting the output. Running on my machine, I get this (as part of a much longer output):

```
* vhdl:
    vhdl (filenames *.vhdl, *.vhd)
```